# google map api javascript marker between the source and destination address based on the distance

Tags: javascript

I have source and destination address. I need to add marker on the particular kilometer between the source and destination address using javascript. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The route between the source and the destination: is it a straight line or one that follows routes (e.g. streets, paths and etc?)

Comment: it is not a straight line.